# How to check the permission granted to SharePoint app-only

Tags: sharepoint-online, app

I have granted permission to a 3rd party app using this method

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs#setting-up-an-app-only-principal-with-tenant-permissions

Now how do I check back what app permission request scope has been granted?

[image: app's permission request xml]

I found the app listed here but it does not state what permission it has.

[image: app permissions list]

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Site contents, find the app, then check the permission.
[image]

Comment: @emily-du-msft the app was not listed in the site content. Tried to find it in the root site collection also it was not listed there...